# Controlling Menus within Internet Explorer with AutoIT

Tags: html, internet-explorer, autoit

I have been struggling over the past 48 hours to create a script that can do some basic things within internet explorer:

1. log into a website
2. select an option from a dropdown menu
3. select a checkbox
4. click an "OK" button

I have no problem logging into the website, but I cannot seem to get the menus working once I am logged in. I have a feeling this is to do with them being dynamically created but my html experience is very limited so I do not know for sure.
I have tried a range of different functions(_IEFormElementGetObjByName,_IEFormGetCollection,_IEFormGetObjByName) among others but cannot seem to make it work.
I cannot post the full script as it contains passwords that I cannot post publicly, but here it is with user/password removed:

```
;Created by SYD-JAMEST from code found at:
;http://solubletech.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/use-autoit-v3-to-make-auto-login-script.html

#Region ;*** Variables
Const $DispatchSite = "https://equipmentrepaircas.interasset.com/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iasdispatchmanager.com%2Fdispatchmanager%2Fj_acegi_cas_security_check" 
Const $uname="user"
Const $pwd="pass%"
#EndRegion

#include <ie.au3>

;*** Navigate to Dispatch Manager and login with username & password
$oIE = _IECreate ($DispatchSite)
$oForm = _IEFormGetObjByName ($oIE, "fm1")
$oQuery1 = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($oForm, "username")
$oQuery2 = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($oForm, "password")

_IEFormElementSetValue ($oQuery1,$uname)
_IEFormElementSetValue ($oQuery2,$pwd)
$oButton=_IEGetObjByName($oIE,"submit")
_IEAction ($oButton, "click")
_IELoadWait($oIE,0)

;** This is the section I cannot get to work
$oForm1 = _IEFormGetObjByName ($oIE, "isc_historyForm")
$test = _IEGetObjById($oForm1, "isc_1F")
$oMenu = _IEGetObjById ($oForm1,"isc_MenuBarButton_0") ;isc_MenuBarButton_0
;$oMenu = _IEGetObjById ($oForm1,"isc_1E")
_IEAction ($test, "focus")
```

This is the html of the area I am trying to access - It doesn't show a name, nor any of the dropdown options that show on screen when selected.

```
<div id="isc_1E" eventproxy="isc_MenuBarButton_0" style="position: absolute; left: 195px; top: 0px; width: 150px; height: 24px; z-index: 200810; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; -webkit-margin-before-collapse: collapse; -webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse;" onscroll="return isc_MenuBarButton_0.$lh()" onfocus="isc.EH.focusInCanvas(isc_MenuBarButton_0,true);" onblur="if(window.isc)isc.EH.blurFocusCanvas(isc_MenuBarButton_0,true);" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="150" height="24" style="table-layout:fixed"><tbody><tr><td class="menuButton" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"><div style="display:inline-block;max-width:100%;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:middle"><div id="isc_1D" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;text-align:left"><img src="https://training.iasdispatchmanager.com/dispatchmanager/ias/images/icons/admin.png" align="TEXTTOP" border="0" suppress="TRUE"> <b>Admin</b></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Post the html of the form you are trying to automate.

Comment: Also, add a Sleep after the login so you make sure the dynamic page is complete.

Comment: Hi Milos - I will attach the html below as it is too long here.
It doesn't show any of the dropdown options (one of which is the one I am looking for) so I have no idea how to control it with AutoIT

Comment: no need to attach the whole html. Attach just the outerhtml of the form isc_historyForm

Answer (score 1):

The second part cannot work. If you get a form object

$oForm1 = _IEFormGetObjByName ($oIE, "isc_historyForm")

you have to go on with the **elements** of this object, like it is done in the first (password) part of your script. 
So your next statement could be something like:

$oTest = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm1, "isc_1F").

Load down the autoIt help file for "user defined function" and look over the examples for "ie-management".
Here the definition and examples for the work with dropdown / select boxes.
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IEFormElementOptionSelect.htm

You may try that. Best regards, Reinhard

Comment: _IEGetObjById ($oIE, "isc_1E") even better since IDs are global and unique.